# Using SimpleModal (jQuery plugin) to display a popup iFrame without unnecessary scrollbars

Tags: jquery, iframe, popup, simplemodal

I'm using SimpleModal:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

And displaying an iframe, as per the example:

```
// Display an external page using an iframe
var src = "http://365.ericmmartin.com/";
$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
    closeHTML:"",
    containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#fff",
        borderColor:"#fff",
        height:450,
        padding:0,
        width:830
    },
    overlayClose:true
});
```

And the popup has *two* sets of scrollbars, one perhaps for the HTML element representing the popup, and one for the iFrame. Try the demo to see: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#examples

Ideally I'd like no scrollbars if the content fits, otherwise a single vertical scrollbar.

Any ideas? Thanks!

- Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only work for the sample code content i.e "eric.martin.com", not sure if you can
control the width for other external content, most probably can't :)

```
 containerCss:{
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    borderColor:"#fff",
    height:450,
    padding:0,
    width:830,
    maxWidth : 800
},
```

Comment: The iframe will be displaying my own content, so I can control it.

Comment: then just make sure the width a few px wider than its content so you only get the vertical bar

Comment: Thanks, got that to work. I didn't need maxWidth, just needed to set width and height in containerCss to be slightly larger than the iFrame set width and height.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make your iframe a little smaller than the modal dimensions.

```
var src = "http://365.ericmmartin.com/";
$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="430" width="810" style="border:0">', {
closeHTML:"",
containerCss:{
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    borderColor:"#fff",
    height:450,
    padding:0,
    width:830
},
overlayClose:true
});
```